# Error establishing a database connection after moving local wordpressmultisite from one directory to another

Tags: multisite, database, errors

Good day together,
as the title mentions, i want to clone a local wordpressmultisite(i use xampp) to another directory. the first existing mutlisite runs under xampp on http://localhost/Wordpress. the second blog of this wpms can be reached under http://localhost/Wordpress/buddha. this multisite is working fine.

Now i want to run a copy of this multisite installation under http://localhost/wp-buddha. So i copied all files and directories from the htdocs/Wordpress directory of xampp and paste it in a directory named wp-buddha ind the htdocs of the xampp directory.

In the next step i created a new databse named buddha by using myphpadmin on localhost. i created also a user for this database named buddha with the passswort buddha.

then i exported all tables from the first multisitedatabes to a sql file and imported the sql file in the nwe buddha databse.

I changed in the new multisite the databse informations such as databasename passwort and databaseuser to the new one.

Now, i my understanding, wordpress should be able to connect to the new databsse called buddha, even if the paths of the subdirectories are not actual.

But when accessing the site over http://localhost/wp-buddha there appears:
Error establishing a databse connection.

I tested the databse informations with a php-script: they arte correct. Can anybody give me a clue why tha database connection isn´t working properly? 
thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing the issues. I will share you how can you move the wp website another folder. Please follow my instruction step by step.

Step 1: Copy the all source code this folder location "http://localhost/Wordpress/buddha" file.
Step 2: When you copy all file then Pleas paste the all source file this folder location "http://localhost/wp-buddha".
Step 3: Create a new database from "http://localhost/phpmyadmin". Then import the database.
Step 4: Open the config.php file and change the only database name.

define('DB_NAME', 'write_db_name_here');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

Step 5: Please go to the database table "wp_options" change the URL link.

Please follow the screenshot instructions. Hopefully, it will be working fine.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RXW633LYUWuPdSBfj-UNKqCA_kzV--8N?usp=sharing

Comment: thank you for your effort! I did the things step by step as you described but nothing changed. I think you provided to create a new database and dont setting passwort or user so that root is set as the default user and '' as the default paswort, so i just have to change the name of the database.
But as i mentioned before, i cheked the log in details for the database by a php script. and they are right. i did the things you describe so many times(at least 10x) but the error still remain the same .

Comment: Thus there must be other reasons why wp can´t connect to the database. i also wrote this after the opening <?php tag: die('hello world'); to test if wp accesses the right wp-config file. The result: it does!!! instead of loading anything or to display the error message error establishing a databse connection there is displayed hello world after accessing the site under http://localhost/wp-buddha